# How can I generate musical notes on iOS and play them?

Tags: ios, midi

I am creating a musical app which generate some music. I already used MIDI functions on Mac to create a MIDI file with MIDI events (unfortunately, I don't remember names of those functions).

I am looking for a way to create instrumental notes (MIDI's or anything else) programmatically in order to play them. I also would like to have multiple channels playing those notes at the same time.

I already tried 'SoundBankPlayer' but apparently, it can't play multiple instruments at the same time.

Have you got an idea?

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be a bit more work than you intended, but you can use PD on iOS to do this. More precisely, you can use [libpd for iOS](http://gitorious.org/pdlib/pages/ObjC) for the synthesis, and then use any number of [community-donated patches](http://puredata.info/community/patches/atct_topic_view?b_start%3aint=20) for the sound you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 5:

MusicSequence, MusicTrack, MusicPlayer will do what you want.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009331

Answer (score 1):

Check out AUSampler AudioUnit for iOS, you'll probably have to delve into Core Audio, which has some learning curve. ;)