# Generating a piano note

Tags: ios, objective-c, coremidi

I am using Objective-C and I would like to generate a piano note. I don't want to use/embed a file at all; I want the phone to generate this sound some how. I don't know if I should be using CoreMIDI to do this (and if I do, I don't know how to use it) or CoreAudio or something else. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I generate musical notes on iOS and play them ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053008/how-can-i-generate-musical-notes-on-ios-and-play-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might a bit of an overkill, but if you want to do something more than generating a piano note, and work with musical generation you might want to have a look at this :

http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/

It's a programming language that allows (among other things) to synthesise audio.

It has been the base for some music applications published on iOs, namely the ones by Smule.